# How to set automatic row height in html excel?

Tags: html, css, excel

I create a simple html file and saved it as "xls". it contains a table with rows.
Some of the rows contain wrapped text.

The height of each row is not auto sized, I can only see one line. If I double click the row in excel, the size will automatically be set to "auto height".

[Here is a short video](https://p-it-s.tinytake.com/sf/MTM3ODI0OF81MDA3OTc2) of how it shows up in excel.

Is there a property I can use to set an automatic height for all rows?

This is how I use it now:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Hello<br style="mso-data-placement:same-cell;" />world</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Maybe is there some magical "mso-data-.." style placement I can use?

Comment: Is it too much trouble to set the auto-height before you export to HTML? It sounds like you want to do the resizing in the HTML itself or during the conversion?

Comment: @AmericanSlime I tried it. I used auto height for each <tr> and also on <td>, it still shows like in video. :/ the only thing that works is when I set the hight by px or cm. (height:30px)

Answer (score 0):

Cells have by default white-space set to **nowrap**, one must set it to **normal** via style or css. This otputs as multiline in excel an

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td style="white-space:normal;">Hello<br style="mso-data-placement:same-cell;" />world</td>
</tr>
```